# Magic Mouse 2 - Do I need to raise my finger?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, mouse

When I use the right click, I need to raise my left finger or it works like a left click. Is this a normal behavior? Can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into mouse preferences and enabling Secondary Click:

[image]

Comment: It's already enabled. But I can't stay with my two fingers on the mouse. I need to lift  one finger to press the right click

Comment: @TryingTrying I think that’s the standard option

Comment: It's the reason I threw mine in a drawer within a day & never looked at it again. 20 years of keeping my left finger just resting whilst clicking the right...